# Convert string date to another format C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I use this function to convert string format to another:

```
public string dateBirthday(string date)
{
   DateTime a = DateTime.Parse(date);
   return a.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

Parameter `date` is 14.10.1991.

Sometimes it does not work. Is it correct way to do that?

Comment: "does not work" *how*?

Comment: I mean sometimes it returns me incoming date as `14.10.1991`

Comment: and what is wrong there? what is input string example?

Comment: Well it'll do that if the current culture uses a period as the date separator... If you want to use a specific culture, you should specify it.

Comment: I use only this inoming value `14.10.1991`

Comment: @JonSkeet: Even with a different culture, would `a.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` still return `"14.10.1991"`?  I could see the parsing failing on the first line of the method, but I can't see how the method would *return* that.

Comment: @David: Yes, because `/` in a custom format string means "the date separator in the formatting culture". So assuming it parses whatever the value is, it can definitely return a string with dots in.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Learned something new today, thanks!

Comment: So, what is reason? How to fix it?

Comment: I need convert this format `14.10.1991` to `14/10/1991`

Comment: @OPV: I've already explained the reason: presumably you're in a culture that uses `.` for a date separator. It's still not clear whether your input format is always dot-separated or not though. Basically, you should specify appropriate cultures in both the parsing and the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public string dateBirthday(string date)
{
   DateTime a = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   //return a.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); // original answer without culture
   return a.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

EDIT:
As Jon Skeet already said, the `/` is culture-dependent and we (you and me;)) did not specify a culture for the `ToString()` function, so the culture of the *host environment* will be used. To get your desired output specify/force a culture that uses `/` as date separator, like `CultureInfo.InvaraintCulture`.

Comment: The OP says in comments that they sometimes get dots in the output, which could still happen with this code.

Comment: It does not work

Comment: @OVP Yes, sry, my fault. Updated my answer